# Is there any way to change edge's weights in networkx during execution

Tags: python, graph, networkx, dijkstra

I am making a travel app in django (python).

I have information about trips and I need to apply Dijkstra's algorithm to valorate if a trip with transfers is ok. I need the following trip is after the previous in the algorithm.

I would like to use networkx with Dijkstra's algorithm but I don't know if I can or if I have to avoid using networkx for my problem.

I have created a graph (reading a csv file with pandas). Each node is an airport and each trip is an edge

```
DG=nx.DiGraph()
for row in spain_flights.iterrows():
    DG.add_edge(row[1]["origin"],
                row[1]["destination"],
                duration=row[1]["duration"],
                price=row[1]["price"])
```

Then I can find the best route (considering price (or duration)):

```
list(nx.dijkstra_path(DG, source="PNA", target="VLL", weight="price"))
```

But If I would like to consider an specific time, I don't know how to solve it. Because the following trip can't be before the actual trip

Comment: Have you tried anything? This [link](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/tutorial.html) should answer the question in the title. Of course you could use networkx for your implementation...

Comment: Yes, I will update the question

Comment: I don't know why I can't access to the documentacion now

Comment: Still what you are asking is not clear to me. If you want to find the shortest path between two routes then you could consider every airport as a node that is connected to all other nodes (airports). When you find the shortest path your can compare it to another path with the same source and destination (given to you by the user I guess?)

Comment: Yes, but I also want to consider that each trip has an arrival and departure ti me. And the following trip has to happen after arrival previous trip time

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you are asking is solved with this:

```
import networkx as nx
from networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.weighted import dijkstra_path

airports = [
    (1, 2, {"price": 100}),
    (1, 3, {"price": 200}),
    (3, 2, {"price": 300}),
    (1, 4, {"price": 100}),
    (4, 2, {"price": 300}),
    (4, 5, {"price": 50}),
    (3, 5, {"price": 500}),
]


user_path = [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 5)] # a route given to you by the user

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from(airports)


# calculate how much the user's journey costs 
user_price = 0
for (src, dst) in user_path:
    user_price += G[src][dst]["price"]

dijkstra_path = dijkstra_path(G, source=1, target=5, weight="price")
dijkstra_price = 0

# calculate how much the dijkstra's journey for the same route costs
for node in range(0, len(dijkstra_path)):
    if node + 1 == len(dijkstra_path):
        break
    dijkstra_price += G[dijkstra_path[node]][dijkstra_path[node + 1]]["price"]

if user_price > dijkstra_price:
    print("User chose a bad route")
else:
    print("User chose a route with optimal price.")
```

```
path: [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 5)]

outputs: 
User chose a bad route
```

```
path:[(1, 4), (4, 5)]

outputs:
User chose a route with optimal price.
```

Comment: I Want to consider also arrival and departure tomes and I Don't Know hoe